# Unable to do annimation on transform group

Tags: wpf, xaml

**How can I perform transforms animation on a UIElement?**

The following code moves a rectangle via annimation but does not transform it when running animation.

I have looked at tutorials and am absolutely confused as to why the following XAML does not work:

XAML:

```
                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                        From="20" To="73"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>-->

                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                        From="0" To="-25"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>

                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        From="0" To="-25"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>

                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0" To="-40"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                    <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0" To="20"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle  x:Name="FrontRectangle" Width="400" Height="246" Fill="Purple" 
                    Canvas.Left="285" Canvas.Top="20" Panel.ZIndex="4" />
        <Rectangle  x:Name="RightRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightBlue" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="774" Canvas.Top="191" Panel.ZIndex="2">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="2.5"/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="60"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-145"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  x:Name="LeftRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightGreen" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="99" Canvas.Top="191" Panel.ZIndex="2" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="2.5"/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="-60"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="145"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  x:Name="MidLeftRectangle" Width="350" Height="160" Fill="LightSeaGreen" 
                    Canvas.Left="159" Canvas.Top="73" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Panel.ZIndex="3" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="-25"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-25"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="20"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle x:Name="MidRightRectangle" Width="350" Height="160" Fill="LightCoral" 
               Canvas.Left="559" Canvas.Top="73" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Panel.ZIndex="3" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="25"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="25"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="20"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void OnSwipedLeft()
{
    var visualState = "SwipeLeftState";
    var success = VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(MyGrid, visualState, true);
    Debug.Assert(success);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to insert a "(TransformGroup.Children)[some_index]" between RenderTransform and the actual type of transform.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SwipeLeftGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="SwipeLeftState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                        From="285" To="159"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>

                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                        From="20" To="73"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>

                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                        From="0" To="-25"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>

                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                        From="0" To="-25"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>

                    <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                        From="0" To="-40"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                    <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                        From="0" To="20"
                                        Duration="0:0:.15">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle  x:Name="FrontRectangle" Width="400" Height="246" Fill="Purple" 
                    Canvas.Left="290" Canvas.Top="20" Panel.ZIndex="4">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  x:Name="RightRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightBlue" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="774" Canvas.Top="191" Panel.ZIndex="2">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="2.5"/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="60"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-145"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  x:Name="LeftRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightGreen" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="99" Canvas.Top="191" Panel.ZIndex="2" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="2.5"/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="-60"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="145"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle  x:Name="MidLeftRectangle" Width="350" Height="160" Fill="LightSeaGreen" 
                    Canvas.Left="159" Canvas.Top="73" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Panel.ZIndex="3" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="-25"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-25"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="20"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>

        <Rectangle x:Name="MidRightRectangle" Width="350" Height="160" Fill="LightCoral" 
               Canvas.Left="559" Canvas.Top="73" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Panel.ZIndex="3" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleX="25"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="25"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="20"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```